# I saw a dream in which i had sex with maid

Tags: sex, ramadan, dream

I saw a dream in which I had sex with my maid, and I don’t properly remember it, but it included oral sex and I think penetration as well. I want to know the meaning of this dream, and I have one more question: I had this dream in Ramadan when evils are chained, so why did I see this dream? And will this dream be considered as having sex with a prostitute?